# Registry DSC failing with BINARY/HEX value

Tags: powershell, dsc

Tearing my hair out on this...I am trying to set a Registry key value via DSC but everything I try fails miserably. Using the native `PSDesiredStateConfiguration` resource and `REGISTRY`.

The problem is that the value I want to set must be in `REG_BINARY` and the value is also in `HEX`. Tried numerous ways of adding in `Hex = $true` and adding all the "`0x`" at the start of each Hex string - none of them seem to work for me. Even tried the below and still failing (`Hex` is referenced out below but tried it on and off and not working for me)...any help on this please

```
Registry SNMPServiceFail {
    Ensure      = "Present"
    Key         = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMPTRAP"
    Force       = $true
    ValueName   = "FailureActions"
    ValueData   = @([byte[]](0x80,0x51,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x14,0x00,0x00,0x00,01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xe0,0x93,0x04,0x00))
    ValueType   = "Binary" 
    #Hex = $true
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
VERBOSE: [LONINENGD187]: LCM:  [ Start  Resource ]  [[Registry]SNMPServiceFail]
VERBOSE: [LONINENGD187]: LCM:  [ Start  Test     ]  [[Registry]SNMPServiceFail]
VERBOSE: [LONINENGD187]:                            [[Registry]SNMPServiceFail] (ERROR) Parameter 'ValueData' has an
invalid value '(128, 81, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 224, 147, 4, 0)' for type
'Binary'
VERBOSE: [LONINENGD187]: LCM:  [ End    Test     ]  [[Registry]SNMPServiceFail]  in 1.5310 seconds.
PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_RegistryResource  failed to execute Test-TargetResource functionality with error message:
(ERROR) Parameter 'ValueData' has an invalid value '(128, 81, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0, 0, 0,
1, 0, 0, 0, 224, 147, 4, 0)' for type 'Binary'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderOperationExecutionFailure
    + PSComputerName        : localhost

VERBOSE: [LONINENGD187]: LCM:  [ End    Set      ]
The SendConfigurationApply function did not succeed.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

When I do a registry export it shows as below - that is what I am trying to ensure it is set to on all my servers:

```
"FailureActions"=hex:80,51,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,e0,93,04,00
```

Comment: did you get an answer that worked for you?  See my comment on Matthias' answer, and if necessary the answer I provided on serverfault to a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

The [Registry resource](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSDscResources/blob/dev/DscResources/MSFT_RegistryResource/MSFT_RegistryResource.psm1) expects the `ValueData` input as a string array, and will then convert it to a byte array internally (see the `ConvertTo-Binary` function in the linked source file).

Cast to `[string[]]` rather than `[byte[]]`:

```
Registry SNMPServiceFail {
    Ensure      = "Present"
    Key         = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SNMPTRAP"
    Force       = $true
    ValueName   = "FailureActions"
    ValueData   = @([string[]](0x80,0x51,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x14,0x00,0x00,0x00,01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0xe0,0x93,0x04,0x00))
    ValueType   = "Binary"
}
```

Comment: thanks for that - unfortunately that is still not doing the trick - still get the same error - any other ideas? I can see in the source it expects "0x" - its definitely the conversion it does not like I have a feeling but can't put my finger on it.

Comment: @lara400 Not really :-\ btw. each byte entry doesn't have to start with `0x`, but _if_ they do, `ConvertTo-Binary` will parse them as hexadecimal.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I didn't try yours but mine over on ServerFault is there with sample code.  The trick is the substring parsing.  It's expecting contiguous 2 character bytes in a string. `$binaryRegistryKeyValue += [Byte]::Parse($singleRegistryKeyValue.Substring($singleRegistryKeyValueIndex, 2), 'HexNumber')`   Let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/865450/dsc-syntax-for-binary-registry-key/865981#865981

Answer (score 1):

For anyone end up here after googling...

You set the ValueData like this if the data is @(255, 255, 255):

```
ValueData = @('ffffff')
```